# Find $E[X_3]$ given the following Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> A Markov chain $\{X_n,n\geq0\}$ with states $0, 1, 2$, has the transition probability
>   matrix
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> \frac12& \frac13 &\frac16\\
> 0&\frac13&\frac23\\
> \frac12&0&\frac12
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   If $P(X_0=0)=P(X_0=1)=\frac14$, find $E[X_3]$.

I reasoned as follows,

Given the above transition probability matrix $\mathbf{P}$, I then found 
$$\mathbf{P}^3=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{13}{36} & \frac{11}{54} & \frac{47}{108} \\
 \frac{4}{9} & \frac{4}{27} & \frac{11}{27} \\
 \frac{5}{12} & \frac{2}{9} & \frac{13}{36} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $P(X_0=2)=1-\left[P(X_0=0)+P(X_0=1)\right]=\frac12.$ I then found the expectation by conditioning, 
$$\begin{aligned}
E[X_3]&=E_{X_0}[E[X_3\vert X_0]]=E\left[\sum_{i=0}^2 iP(X_3=i\vert X_0)\right]\\&=E[P(X_3=1\vert X_0)]+2E[P(X_3=2\vert X_0)]\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^2P(X_3=1\vert X_0=j)P(X_0=j)+2\sum_{j=0}^2P(X_3=2\vert X_0=j)P(X_0=j)
\end{aligned}$$
so
$$\begin{aligned}E[X_3]&=P(X_0=0)\mathbf{P}^3_{01}+P(X_0=1)\mathbf{P}^3_{11}+P(X_0=2)\mathbf{P}^3_{21}+\\&+2\left[P(X_0=0)\mathbf{P}^3_{02}+P(X_0=1)\mathbf{P}^3_{12}+P(X_0=2)\mathbf{P}^3_{22}\right]\\\\&=\frac14\cdot\frac{11}{54}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{27}+\frac12\cdot\frac29+2\left(\frac14\cdot\frac{47}{108}+\frac14\cdot\frac{11}{27}+\frac12\cdot\frac{13}{36}\right)\\&=\frac{53}{54}.\end{aligned}$$
Would this be correct?

Comment: I haven't checked the arithmethic, but it looks right otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of matrices, it suffices to compute
$$\pi=[1/4\quad1/4\quad1/2]P^3[0\quad1\quad2]^\top$$